# Is this an unsuitable cassette lockring tool?

Tags: cassette, freewheel, tools

I can't get my lockring tool to fit my cassette's lockring. The tool is about 1mm i diameter bigger than the lockring, although they have "hills and valleys" that line up.

Here's the lockring:

[image]

Here's the lockring tool:

[image]

Here's the tool in the lockring before I try to engage the lockring with the tool:

[image]

And here's the tool nestling on top of the lockring, but it doesn't fit in at all:

[image]

The lockring says "LB SHIMANO" on it. The tool says it's compatible with Shimano Hyperglide. Do I have the wrong tool for the job?

Comment: There are about a half-dozen different common cassette lockring standards (and no doubt about 2 dozen more less common ones).  Assuming there are no burrs on either the tool or the ring, preventing them from mating, you have the wrong tool.

Comment: It might be worth measuring the dianeter of the tool you're using (which you know is about 1mm too big). Then [Park Tools](http://www.parktool.com/category/cassette-freewheel) make a decent selection of lockrings, you may see one that fits. There's a few of them about.

Comment: First of all: are you sure you need to remove the freewheel (I'm pretty sure that's a freewheel, not a cassette)? I see from your other question that you have a broken axle, I assume it's the same wheel. If you're just trying to fix the axle, you can leave the freewheel alone.

Comment: When you restrict to Shimano, theres 1 freewheel tool and 1 cassette tool (up to variants that don't matter, e.g. having a guide pin, or coming with a built in handle or whatever). The thing there looks to be a cassette tool with guide pin similar to the Park Tool FR-5G.

Comment: @MikeBaranczak Yes, I've replace my chainwheels and chain, and wanted to replace the cassette sprokets. Well, I've realised this is a freewheel instead, and I'd like to replace it for an optimised drivetrain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think thats a Shimano freewheel, rather than a cassette.

A Shimano freewheel needs a tool like a Park Tool FR-1 (or FR-1.2 or FR-1.3), which has 12 splines and a diameter of around 23 mm rather than the Shimano cassette tool (Park Tool FR-5 or its variants), which also has 12 splines but a diameter of around 23.4mm.

See [this link](http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/cassette-and-freewheel-removal-and-installation#article-section-6) from Park Tool on how to remove it.

Comment: It looks like the cassette needs a tool in the 2 dimples you see there to remove it so that looks, as the others say, like the freewheel you're wanting to undo.

Comment: You don't need to engage the 2 dimples. If you can't get the proper tool, you can take a punch and hit those dimples or use a pin spanner and destroy the freewheel to remove it. Directions are [here](http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/freewheel-destructive-removal). The proper freewheel remover will just go into the splines and not touch the dimples.

Comment: I remember probably 20 years ago now having to take cassettes off by tapping that locking round with a hammer and screwdriver. It worked and when you're a kid you don't necessarily have the best tools for the job always.

Comment: Yes, its one way to get it off, but its more work than just getting the proper tool and a crescent wrench (and prevents re-using the freewheel; the one pictured looks to be in pretty decent condition).

Comment: I think you can do it without ruining anything except maybe the lock ring if it's too tight. I agree, get the right tool for the job though.